# Check whether an attribute is a (inherited) property

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I am working with a custom framework that has a lot of custom `__getattrs__` and `__setattrs__`. Basically, if the attribute name isn't something specified, it throws and error. I would still like to be able to add properties though.

So far I got away with editing the **setattr** to

```
elif isinstance(self.__class__.__dict__[name], property):
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

but this fails with inheritance is involved. Is there some good python solution or do I just have to recurse through all the parents until I find or don't find the property?

edit: To clarify the line `Basically, if the attribute name isn't something specified, it throws and error` above

```
list_a = ['attr1', 'attr2']
list_b = ['attr3', 'attr4']

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in list_a:
        result = list_a_action(name)
    elif name in list_b:
        result = list_b_action(name)
    else:
        raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
```

Comment: What does ```the attribute name isn't something specified``` mean?  If possible would you make some example classes that exhibit/mimic the symptom you are trying to avoid and add that to the question? ... http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @wwii Does that edit make more sense?